# Response encoding of Google App Engine (can not change response encoding)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, servlets, character-encoding

```
public class FeedUpdaterServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    req.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    resp.setLocale(Locale.TAIWAN);
    resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world!!@!");
            out.println("我是人");  //some chinese character
    out.println(resp.getCharacterEncoding());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  }

}
```

web xml

```
<locale-encoding-mapping-list>
        <locale-encoding-mapping>
            <locale>zh_TW</locale>
            <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
        </locale-encoding-mapping>
    </locale-encoding-mapping-list>
```

Output:
Hello, world!!@! ??? ISO-8859-1

It seems that the encoding of the respond can not be changed, what is happening???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for [`ServletResponse.setContentType(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) clearly state that calling this method has no effect if called after `getWriter()` method is called.

This does the trick:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello, world!!@!");
    out.println("我是人");  //some chinese character
    out.println(resp.getCharacterEncoding());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: How do you embbed this response into a particular section of your html file?